# Custom legend for corrplot

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I'm trying to build a lower triangular correlation matrix for my data.

I'm using `corrplot` and so far I've been happy with it. The only issue that I have is that I want a custom legend, where all `0->0.1` values will be marked as `red` whereas `0.1 -> 1` values will gradually turn from white to blue.

I used a specific [website](https://www.strangeplanet.fr/work/gradient-generator/index.php) to generate a custom gradient from white to blue. And then I feed it to `colorRampPalette`.

Here's my code:

```
cor <- read.table("path/to/data", header=T, sep='\t')
col <- colorRampPalette(c("FA0A1A", "#FFFFFF", "#E0E6FD", "#C1CDFC", "#A3B4FB", "#849CFA", "#6583F8", "#476AF7", "#2851F6", "#0A39F5"))

corrplot(abs(cor),
         method = "color",
         type = "lower",
         tl.pos = "n",
         col = col(100),
         cl.lim = c(0,1))
```

The result I get from this is the following:
[image]

The red part does not appear on the legend. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using a three red-white-blue gradient? This is what I've got on this site: `#FF0000 #FF3333 #FF6666 #FF9999 #FFCCCC #FFFFFF #CCCCFF #9999FF #6666FF #3232FF #0000FF`

Comment: @IaroslavDomin this is not the case with my plot. If I do that, then ~0.5 values will be white, something I don't want't. I wan't veeeery low values to be explicitly marked red, so it will be easier to spot them.

Comment: You can try to play with this palette. Sort of widen the white area by manually adding more white codes in the middle of the vector and removing red and blue.